# How do I implement a search page on a mkdocs site?

Tags: mkdocs

I have a working search box in my nav bar, what I'd like to implement now is a search *page*, eg `mysite/search.html` - ideally so I can set up links to my site with `mysite/search.html?q=QUERYSTRING`

An example of this working in practice is shown [here](http://readthedocs.sheets.ch/search?q=test).

I'm using the material theme and my config is [here](https://github.com/sasjs/sasjs.io/blob/master/mkdocs.yml).  The site is [here](https://sasjs.io).

The `search.html` appears [to be in the material repo](https://github.com/squidfunk/mkdocs-material/blob/master/src/partials/search.html), however it doesn't appear in my build.  I'm using mkdocs v1.1.2 and mkdocs-material 5.5.0